# Function Import Entity Framework orderby

Tags: function, gridview, frameworks, import, entity

I'm trying to sort a **gridview** with my objectdatasource which uses a function import (stored proc) from my entity model. The guide I was follow was from
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/using-the-entity-framework-and-the-objectdatasource-control-part-3-sorting-and-filtering

Which has this code:

```
public IEnumerable<Department> GetDepartments(string sortExpression)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortExpression))
        {
            sortExpression = "Name";
        }
        return context.Departments.Include("Person").OrderBy("it." + sortExpression).ToList();
    }
```

How can I do an OrderBy if I'm calling a stored proc?

My code:

```
  If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortExpression) Then
                sortExpression = "Status"
            End If

            retReq = dataContext.usp_GetReport(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, period, Nothing, Nothing, _
                            Nothing, Nothing, Nothing).ToList()
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

**Update - Resolution**

I'm sure that there's a better way of making the sort functionality work in my case. But this is the method I did, it works but if there's anyone that could help me simplify it, please let me know thanks.

Derived from msdn's documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.96).aspx#Y1200

```
If sortExpression IsNot Nothing Then
                If sortExpression = "StatusDate DESC" Then
                    retReq = dataContext.usp_GetReport(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, period, Nothing, Nothing, _
                       Nothing, Nothing, Nothing).OrderByDescending(Function(test As usp_GetReport_Result) test.StatusDate).ToList()

                ElseIf sortExpression = "StatusDate" Then
                    retReq = dataContext.usp_GetReport(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, period, Nothing, Nothing, _
                       Nothing, Nothing, Nothing).OrderBy(Function(test As usp_GetReport_Result) test.StatusDate).ToList()

                End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either 
1) sort inside the stored-procedure, or
2) sort the returned data using Linq to objects.

e.g.

```
var sorted = retReq.OrderBy(x=>x.SomeProperty);
```

obviously 2) is going to sort the results which may not be what you require, if for instance your sproc is returning top(n).

Comment: I tried using the line of code you've provided, but intellisense wasn't available for the "OrderBy" function. Would I use it after it has returned the value back to my application layer? the code is inside a function which returns an IEnumerable(Of usp_GetReport_Result) and connected through my objectdatasource's SelectMethod

Comment: And actually, sorting the results is what i intend to do. And to be exact, i want to sort a gridview when clicking the column headers.

Comment: You need the equivalent of C#'s "using System.Linq;", probably "import System.Linq"

Comment: Still didn't show an OrderBy function for retReq. Do I have to specify a type for sorted? I have it as  `Dim sorted = Nothing` . And am i supposed to do it after the line `retReq = dataContext.usp_GetReport(...).ToList()` ? or outside the call? ... Thanks, and really appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this works, but I may have different scenario with my function import, which doesn't really make sense. But i've posted my manual-fix for now. as it works on my gridview sort. thanks

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the Linq VB samples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737912.  I'm not sure how you translate lambda expressions into VB, but you can just use query syntax instead ' From x in retReq Order by x.SomeProperty'.